# Understanding init script faults with sysctl

Tags: boot, opensuse, init, systemctl

I made my own init script for starting a Mono web application within `mod-mono-server2` container (I didn't use `AutoHosting`, I'm aware of it).

When I had openSUSE 11.4 with `init` I was able to read on console exactly what went wrong. Now I had to migrate my app to a server running openSUSE 12.1 that uses `systemctl`, and it's a mess to figure out why it fails to start.

The startup command is just a typical `sudo -u mono-user mod-mono-server2 [params]` that writes the PID to a file in `/var/run/spambusters/` (to kill it when I want to stop).
When I try to do `/etc/init.d/spambusters start` I just get a generic `Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.`.

But I can't get more information.........

```
spambusters@dom:~/source> sudo systemctl status spambusters.service
spambusters.service - LSB: Spambusters instance (as spambusters)
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/spambusters)
      Active: failed since Fri, 07 Sep 2012 20:37:56 +0200; 1min 37s ago
     Process: 29731 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/spambusters start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/spambusters.service
          â”” 29744 sudo -u spambusters /usr/bin/mod-mono-server2 --nonstop --port 8089 --address 127.0.0.1 --applicat...
spambusters@dom:~/so
```

System log `/var/log/messages` only contains

```
Sep  7 20:37:56 dom sudo:     root : TTY=console ; PWD=/ ; USER=spambusters ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2 --nonstop --port 8089 --address 127.0.0.1 --applications /:/home/spambusters/srv/www/domains/www.burnthespam.info/htdocs
```

While I understand that this question could also be suitable for serverfault.com because deals with server administration, **my straight question is**

### How do I find more information about failure in an init script when root process is systemctl instead of init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS uses systemd-journald,

```
journalctl -a _SYSTEMD_UNIT=spambusters.service
```

(Latest systemd version shows the same in `systemctl status`, but OpenSuSE has an older one.)

---

Also, **do not use `sudo`** if you only want it to run as a different user. **Use `User=spambusters`** instead.

Comment: Can you explain the sudo part better? Where do I use User=spambusters?

Comment: @djechelon: In the `spambusters.service` unit, of course. See the *systemd.exec(5)* manual page, where `User=` is described.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. My script (inherited from a system where I was using init) is /etc/init.d/spambusters and is written according to init format, exactly like sshd, mysql, apache2 scripts. All of them are present in my openSUSE 12.1 system that uses systemd instead of init, and apache2 gave me headaches too because I couldn't easily know why sometimes it didn't start (but I managed to fix...). So I basically have no spambusters.service file